# Microsoft Edge and ajax timing

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have code with an ajax request that has been running fine for over two years but fails intermittently in Microsoft Edge.

```
set_page : function()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ajax/set_page',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'book_id' : this.book_id, 'page' : this.page},
    });
},
```

ajax/set_page is a php function that updates the column 'page' in the book table.

When I debug the code in Chrome, the database is updated as soon as I step over the $.ajax call. In Edge, the database is not updated until the program thread in javascript is finished.

```
set_page {
-----------> Chrome db -> page = 11, Edge db -> page = 11
   $.ajax({...POST}); 
-----------> Chrome db -> page = 12, Edge db -> page = 11
};
};
};
----------> Edge db -> page = 12, ajax success!
```

Usually that is not a problem but occasionally the thread has a lot of extra processing and when the ajax/set_page php function is finally called, the $_POST values are null.

Has anybody else seen this sort of behavior in Edge? Is there any way to kick off the ajax request so it calls my php function right away?

Maybe my question should be: Why are my $_POST variables sometimes null in my ajax call in Edge? Is there some way to debug them between the $.ajax call and my php function?
....................

After more debugging, a page reload that happens in IE11 (to fix a flash/IE11 bug) is causing the problem.

```
set_page {
-----------> Chrome db -> page = 11, Edge db -> page = 11
   $.ajax({...POST}); 
-----------> Chrome db -> page = 12, Edge db -> page = 11
};
};
if last_page
   do stuff
   if IE11
     location.reload()
};
----------> 
not last page: Edge db -> page = 12, ajax success!
last page: Edge db -> page = null, book_id = null
```

So I have two issues:

1. it looks like when the page is reloaded, the POST parameters are cleaned up but the ajax request is still executed.
2. the Edge browser is being identified as IE11.

It looks like the IE11/flash bug was fixed in Edge so I should be able to remove the reload but I need to do some more testing to make sure.

Comment: how exactly are you debugging this?

Comment: @cmorrissey I have a breakpoint set on my $.ajax call in the Developer Tools. Then I "step over" the $.ajax call.

Comment: @Emily I think the more important part of the debugging is how you determine that the database has been updated. Still, if you do determine that it's postponing the ajax call, maybe `setImmediate()` could solve the issue? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453394.aspx

Comment: @Katana314 When I am at the breakpoint, after I step over the $.ajax call, while I am still in the set_page function, I refresh the book table in phpmyadmin. At that point, in Chrome, the database is updated but it is not in ME. 

The ajax call stays "pending" in the Network tab in the Developer Tools until the javascript thread is complete. 

Maybe my question should be: Why are my $_POST variables sometimes null in my ajax call in ME?

Comment: @Emily Wait, `$_POST` variables? That sounds very much like you're referring to the PHP code; which would imply the request has already reached the server and completed. That sounds more like there's a bad request issue, rather than just a timing issue. When you look at the request in the Network tab of Edge, do you see all your parameters being sent to the server correctly?

Comment: @Katana314 I have been trying to find the parameters in the Edge Dev Tools all afternoon. Do you know where they are?  The Parameters tab is empty—even for the ajax calls that work. In Chrome, I see the parameters in Form Data. I see the correct values in the javascript when the $.ajax call is built but by the time it gets to my PHP, both $_POST values are null (sometimes).

Comment: First, turn off JS breakpoints so it's not pausing mid-request. Do your request, and then go to the Network tab, click on the ajax call by path, and then on the right side, click the Body tab. Under there, click "Request Body" (Note that this tab will always be empty in a GET request).

Answer (score 2):

your ajax call is asynchronous, so the function runs (hits your breakpoint in your dev tools) but that doesn't mean that it has sent the data to your backed and received a response back that the operation completed.

```
set_page : function()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ajax/set_page',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'book_id' : this.book_id, 'page' : this.page},
        success: function(data){
            console.log('the page was set');
        }/* make sure there is no trailing comma*/
    });
},
```

Comment: Hi there, i am facing the same issue in IE Edge, IE11 not in chrome. $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: serviceUrl,
            data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType : 'application/json',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log("success");
            },
            error : function(errorMsg) {
                console.log("error");
            }
        });                                              any help?